# org.json breaking change with update

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have a legacy system at hand. This system was using an old version of `org.json.JSONObject`. For this version the following json was valid

```
{
  "key" = "value",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

The json is actually invalid but for this version it was valid.

Now I upgraded the version to the latest one and everything is failing because of `=`. I get error that `Expected ':' at char XX` everytime. I could change my local tests and integ tests but what about clients? I have no idea whether they pass `=` or `:` and knowing them they would be passing `=`.

Is there a way i make the latest version on JSONObject accept `=` as valid assignment and alternative to `:` or is this a lost cause?